# How can I print a portion of a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Say for example I would want to print half a quarter or a certain section of a 2D array how would I change the code below. Just in general printing only certain sections like if there were ten rows and columns how would I print the last 2 rows and last 2 columns,

```
for (int row = 0; row < example.length; row++) {
for (int column = 0; column < example[row].length; column++) {    
    System.out.print(" "+example[row][column] + "\t|");  
    }
  System.out.println(); 
  }
```

Comment: First question: What quarter?

Comment: just in general printing only certain sections like if there were ten rows and colums how would i print the last 2 rows and last 2 colums

Comment: @hephaestus hades can u update the post with your 2d array. It will help give the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the loop count to print according to your wish.  Say for example

```
for (int row = 0; row < (example.length)/2; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < (example.length)/2; column++) 
    {    
        System.out.print(" "+example[row][column] + "\t|");  
    }
    System.out.println(); 
}
```

This will print half of your rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can try playing with the loop:

```
String[][] example = new String[][] { { "a", "b", "c", "d" }, { "e", "f", "g", "h" } };

for (int row = 0; row < example.length; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < example[row].length / 2; column++) {
        System.out.print(" " + example[row][column] + "\t|");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
for (int row = 0; row < example.length / 2; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < example[row].length; column++) {
        System.out.print(" " + example[row][column] + "\t|");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
for (int row = example.length / 2; row < example.length; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < example[row].length; column++) {
        System.out.print(" " + example[row][column] + "\t|");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
for (int row = 0; row < example.length; row++) {
    for (int column = example[row].length / 2; column < example[row].length; column++) {
        System.out.print(" " + example[row][column] + "\t|");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
for (int row = 0; row < example.length; row++) {
    for (int column = example[row].length / 4; column < example[row].length; column++) {
        System.out.print(" " + example[row][column] + "\t|");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
for (int row = 0; row < example.length; row++) {
    for (int column = example[row].length * 3 / 4; column < example[row].length; column++) {
        System.out.print(" " + example[row][column] + "\t|");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
```

Outputs:

```
 a  | b |
 e  | f |
----------------------------------------
 a  | b | c | d |
----------------------------------------
 e  | f | g | h |
----------------------------------------
 c  | d |
 g  | h |
----------------------------------------
 b  | c | d |
 f  | g | h |
----------------------------------------
 d  |
 h  |
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: lets say i want to get  .................................................................................... b | c  | d | ...................................................................................................................
f| g  | h |                             . how would i do that

Comment: or just print   |d| ..............................................................................................................................................................|h|.......................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scanner to take custom row and col values. Of course, you would need to check if the values provided are in the lengths of each prior to printing so you don't get any IndexOutOfBounds errors (not pictured here).

```
int[][] example = new int[10][10];

    int count = 0;

//populate array

    for (int row = 0; row < example.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < example[row].length; column++) {    
            example[row][column] = count;
            count++;
        }
    }

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter row start: ");
    int rowStart = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter row end: ");
    int rowEnd = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter col start: ");
    int colStart = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter col end: ");
    int colEnd = sc.nextInt();

    for (int row = rowStart; row < rowEnd; row++) {
        for (int column = colStart; column < colEnd; column++) {    
            System.out.print(" "+example[row][column] + "\t|");  
        }
        System.out.println(); 
    }
    sc.close();
```